# Inner join after left join to return null

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to return every `p` row, and have null values for `u.id` and `u.first_name` if they dont have `ROLE_ADMIN`. When I perform this query I get empty result. If I use `left join` instead of `inner` I get incorrect results. How to filter left join so that If nothing matches I still get returned p rows with null values for `u.id` and `u.first_name`?

Note: I added `p.id = 13455` at the end just for test purposes.

```
select u.id, u.first_name, p.id
from sub p
    left join oub oj on oj.id = p.sub_id
    left join jhi_user u on u.oub_id= oj.id 
    inner join jhi_user_authority ua on ua.user_id = u.id where ua.authority_name = 'ROLE_ADMIN' and p.id = 13544;
```

Answer (score 1):

use left join like below

```
select u.id, u.first_name, p.id
from sub p
    left join oub oj on oj.id = p.sub_id
    left join jhi_user u on u.oub_id= oj.id 
    left join 
   ( select * from
jhi_user_authority where authority_name = 'ROLE_ADMIN' 
)  ua on ua.user_id = u.id
  where p.id = 13544;
```

Comment: I get the same result as when I use regular left join. Last left join is returning null but one before that has some values, therefore it will return all of the results, ignoring last join filter.

Answer (score 1):

I think the logic you want is:

```
select 
    ua.user_id,
    case when ua.user_id is not null then u.first_name end as first_name,
    p.id
from sub p
left join oub oj 
    on oj.id = p.sub_id
left join jhi_user u 
    on u.oub_id= oj.id 
left join jhi_user_authority ua 
    on ua.user_id = u.id
    and ua. authority_name = 'ROLE_ADMIN'
    and u.id is not null
```

Comment: Is it possible to get only rows where user is present? I want to fetch all users or return only one p row with null as user value. With your query I am getting all users with null values and one real user.

Answer (score 0):

So I solved it like this:

```
select u.id, u.first_name, p.id
from sub p
    left join oub oj on oj.id = p.sub_id
    left join jhi_user u on u.id =
    (select ru.id from jhi_user ru inner join jhi_user_authority rua on rua.user_id = ru.id and rua.authority_name = 'ROLE_ADMIN' where ru.oub_id= oj.id)
    where p.id = 18774;
```